# Auto vacuuming high-write, high-update, and mostly read table types

Tags: postgresql, amazon-rds, maintenance, autovacuum

What are good *auto vacuum* settings (recommendations) for tables like:

- **High Write Table Insert load**

  Range between 30-10,000 inserts in a day. The table can idle for weeks without load, but can get bursts of inserts at least three times a week.
- **High Update Table**

  It uses partition table data, is 3-8 times the size of my table from a single insert.
- **High Write Table**

  A single row gets updated only once, but bursts of unique key updates in a day
  and needs to be updated it could be 30-10,000 key update.
- **High Read Table**

  Most tables are high read tables set to fill factor 80 for my data warehouse, housing table that came from the computation of **High Update Table**

My deletes happen monthly and in batches. Everything relating to the key gets deleted or moved as backup.

Currently my fill factor is set to be 10-20 for **high update table**.

Using TDS db.t3.large but I switch to db.t3.micro during low traffic.

Also, does setting fill factor really low slow down selects?

Answer (score 5):

That question is too broad, but here are some pointers about configuring autovacuum:

- For tables that receive bulk inserts, run an explicit `VACUUM` afterwards or use PostgreSQL v13.
- For tables with many updates, a `fillfactor` of 70 to 90 (depending on row size) is a good thing **if no updated columns are indexed**. 10 or 20 is just a crazy waste of space.
- There is no need to care about autovacuum for tables that are only read.
- With mass deletes, there is nothing much you can do. If you can use partitioning, that pain may vanish completely.

Of course low `fillfactor` will have a negative impact on query performance; that is the price you are paying for more efficient data modifications:

- For sequential scans, the impact is clear: you have to read all that empty space too.
- For index scans that read only a single row, there will be no performance impact.
- Index scans that read several rows are somewhere in the middle, since they will have to read more blocks if `fillfactor` is low, because the rows will be spread across more blocks.
- Don't forget the impact on caching efficiency: If your blocks consist mostly of air, the RAM used for caching will also mostly contain dead space.

Answer (score 4):

There is a document on the internet that discusses **AUTOVACUUM** in PostgreSQL on RDS titled: [Understanding autovacuum in Amazon RDS for PostgreSQL environments](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/understanding-autovacuum-in-amazon-rds-for-postgresql-environments/)

In particular ....

> Autovacuum is a daemon that automates the execution of VACUUM and ANALYZE (to gather statistics) commands. Autovacuum checks for bloated tables in the database and reclaims the space for reuse.

Essentially I would recommend running the defaults as **AUTOVACUUM** will take care of cleaning up the tables and updating the statistics for you.

You will however have to monitor to see if your PostgreSQL RDS instance is doing a good job of keeping up with housekeeping. You can use the script taken from the article I mentioned:

```
SELECT
relname AS TableName
,n_live_tup AS LiveTuples
,n_dead_tup AS DeadTuples
,last_autovacuum AS Autovacuum
,last_autoanalyze AS Autoanalyze
FROM pg_stat_user_tables;
```

This will produce something like this:

```
        tablename         | livetuples | deadtuples |          autovacuum           |          autoanalyze
--------------------------+------------+------------+-------------------------------+-------------------------------
 cfgdateval               |       1666 |          0 | 2020-02-26 12:32:13.851917+00 | 2020-02-26 12:32:13.87854+00
 atcontval                |       2940 |          0 | 2018-06-07 09:53:30.664645+00 | 2019-11-28 15:10:15.256083+00
 cfgintval                |        206 |          0 | 2020-02-26 12:32:13.815353+00 | 2020-02-26 12:32:13.815787+00
 cfgaggval                |         26 |          0 |                               | 2017-07-26 18:56:23.161035+00
 cfgobjval                |       3366 |          0 | 2020-02-26 12:32:13.933712+00 | 2020-02-26 12:32:13.959892+00
 atintval                 |     169080 |          0 |                               | 2018-06-07 09:53:33.821121+00
 atobjval                 |     259728 |          0 |                               | 2018-06-07 09:53:32.557788+00
 cfgstrval                |       1616 |          0 | 2020-02-26 12:32:13.752583+00 | 2020-02-26 12:32:13.803132+00
 ataggval                 |     182790 |          0 |                               | 2018-06-07 09:53:30.566021+00
 coolinking               |      59375 |          0 | 2017-05-05 08:47:09.865774+00 | 2017-05-05 09:36:07.292082+00
 cooobject                |      31791 |         13 |                               | 2017-05-05 09:01:06.672438+00
```

If you have tables containing lots of dead tuples and no **AUTOVACUUM** has been run, then you might want to consider tuning the Autovacuum settings:

```
select category, name,setting,unit,source,min_val,max_val from pg_settings where category = 'autovacuum' ;
```

Output:

```
  category |                name                 | setting   | unit |       source       | min_val |  max_val   | boot_val 
------------+-------------------------------------+-----------+------+--------------------+---------+------------+-----------
Autovacuum | autovacuum                          | on        |      | default            |         |            | on
Autovacuum | autovacuum_analyze_scale_factor     | 0.05      |      | configuration file | 0       | 100        | 0.1
Autovacuum | autovacuum_analyze_threshold        | 50        |      | default            | 0       | 2147483647 | 50
Autovacuum | autovacuum_freeze_max_age           | 200000000 |      | default            | 100000  | 2000000000 | 200000000
Autovacuum | autovacuum_max_workers              | 3         |      | default            | 1       | 262143     | 3
Autovacuum | autovacuum_multixact_freeze_max_age | 400000000 |      | default            | 10000   | 2000000000 | 400000000
Autovacuum | autovacuum_naptime                  | 30        | s    | configuration file | 1       | 2147483    | 60
Autovacuum | autovacuum_vacuum_cost_delay        | 20        | ms   | default            | -1      | 100        | 20
Autovacuum | autovacuum_vacuum_cost_limit        | -1        |      | default            | -1      | 10000      | -1
Autovacuum | autovacuum_vacuum_scale_factor      | 0.1       |      | configuration file | 0       | 100        | 0.2
Autovacuum | autovacuum_vacuum_threshold         | 50        |      | default            | 0       | 2147483647 | 50
```

See [A Case Study of Tuning Autovacuum in Amazon RDS for PostgreSQL](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/a-case-study-of-tuning-autovacuum-in-amazon-rds-for-postgresql/) for more details for when and if you should modify the **AUTOVACUUM** settings.

Generally PostgreSQL does a good job of keeping with housekeeping.